# Jdeveloper 11gR1: java.lang.IllegalStateException when opening project

Tags: jdeveloper

I installed 11.1.1.5 just now, and am getting this error every time I try to open a project or a directory in a project, I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.

And it doesn't display the files.

To exclude any other factors I did a fresh install in a new Ubuntu VM image - same problem.
I'm really at my wit's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting all local projects and checking out the source code again.